# Latest version of an artifact from Apache Archiva

Tags: archiva, maven-metadata

Is there some kind of parametrized url on archiva, where I can get the latest snapshot/release of an artifact? 
sth like 
https://myhappyarchiva.com/archiva/repository/com.example/com/example/myproject/LATEST/myproject-LATEST.jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That feature is not yet available, however you might like to file an issue at http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRM. A related issue is http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRM-805.

To achieve this today, the best thing to do is either:

- use the XMLRPC interface to retrieve the versions and select the latest (you can use Maven libraries to do that if it's for Maven) [[1](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/archiva/branches/archiva-1.3.x/archiva-modules/archiva-web/archiva-xmlrpc/archiva-xmlrpc-api/src/main/java/org/apache/archiva/web/xmlrpc/api/SearchService.java?revision=900340&view=markup)] [[2](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/archiva/branches/archiva-1.3.x/archiva-modules/archiva-web/archiva-xmlrpc/archiva-xmlrpc-client/src/main/java/org/apache/archiva/web/xmlrpc/client/SampleClient.java?revision=900340&view=markup)]
- if you know the repository will be a Maven repository, you can grab the maven-metadata.xml file from Archiva and read the `<release>` or `<latest>` element

Comment: 4 years later, is this possible yet? I am changing my url from a working 'com.example:library:2.0.300-SNAPSHOT' to 'com.example:library:2.0.*-SNAPSHOT', which does not work. :(

Comment: @Brett, we are also interested in this feature. Is it yet a feature of `Apache Archiva`?

Comment: I think so... is this what you're looking for? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRM-1843

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:
"http://myhappyarchiva.com/archiva/restServices/archivaServices/searchService/artifact?r=#releases&g=com.myhappyarchiva&a=myproject&v=LATEST"

The basics are:
"http://[host_name]/archiva/restServices/archivaServices/searchService/artifact?r=[release_option]&g=[group_id]&a=[artifact_id]&v=[version]&c=[classifer]"

- [host_name] is like: dev.foo.com
- [release_option] is like: "snapshots" or "releases"
- [group_id] is like: com.foo
- [version] is like: LATEST or some number like 1.0
- [classifer] is like: javadoc, sources, or assembly

The labels are displayed in the tables on archiva. So you can easily look up the references.

I believe you can use "p" to be packaging as well. It can be like: "jar","pom","javadoc" basically file types. So that would look like,
"&p=jar" added onto the request.

It you are following the requests it sometimes goes through a 307 temporary redirect and 302 found redirect before the repo starts to download.

You do this with curl or wget. Or in a script (I made a ruby script).

Example of wget:
https://archiva.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/userguide/querying-artifacts.html